# Imagemagick resized pictures are different using a single command or two commands

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I can't understand why those two scripts seem to produce a different result, given that the second one is like the first one but separated into two commands.

First script:

```
convert lena_std.tif -compress None -resize 160x160 -compress None -resize 32x32 test1.bmp
```

Second script:

```
convert lena_std.tif -compress None -resize 160x160 test2.bmp
convert test2.bmp -compress None -resize 32x32 test3.bmp
```

I use the following command to check the difference between the results:

```
convert test1.bmp test3.bmp -metric AE -compare diff.bmp
```

I use Imagemagick on Ubuntu 22.04. My `convert -version` indicates: `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25`.

Comment: Imagemagick processes as doubles (floats). But when you write to a bmp, it saves as uint8 (integers). So you are losing quality when you do it as two commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you scale you interpolate pixels.

Roughly, the code considers the pixel at `(x,y)` in the **result**, and computes where it comes from in the source. This is usually not an exact pixel, more like an area, when you scale down, or part of a pixel, when you scale up. So to make up the color of the pixel at `(x,y)` some math is applied: if you scale down, some averaging of the source area, and if you scale up, something that depends on how close the source is to the edge of the pixel and how different the color of neighboring pixels are.

This math can be very simple (the color of the closest pixel), simple (some linear average), a bit more complex (bi-cubic interpolation) or plain magic (sinc/Lanczos), the more complex forms giving the better results.

So, in one case, you obtain a result directly from the source to the pixel you want, and in the other you obtain the final result from an approximation of what the image would look at the intermediate size.

Another way to see it is that each interpolation has a spatial frequency response (like a filter in acoustics), and in one case you apply a single filter and in the other one you compose two filters.